# Is a php query string containing two question mark separators '?' problematic? (file.php?parm1=val1&parm2=val2?parm3=val3&...)

Tags: php

So here's some more detail behind this question...

I have two systems from two different vendors, both proprietary. We'll call them System A and System B. Both systems function as stand alone entities, but System B provides some additional and very specific functionality lacking in System A. The vendor behind System B integrates with System A on a rather basic level (System B integrates with other vendor systems similar to System A within the same market). While System B is a php driven application, System A is not. The integration method goes something like this:

System B exports a structured control file (aka a text file) containing various parameter/value pairs. System A is designed to import the control file into System A. System A takes the data in the control file, combines it with some of it's own data, and constructs a URI. This URL is presented as a user-clickable link on the appropriate page within System A. It is this URI that contains the double '?' within the query string. This same URI contains what I can only describe as a post-back URI (a specific URI on System A to receive data back from System B, forming bi-directional communication).

So the user action of clicking the link performs the following:

Step 1: System A passes a series of parameters and values to System B within the query string to 'file.php'.

Step 2: System B receives the data from System A, performs some validation and what not, writes some information into the database, and in the process spawns a new child browser window separate from System A. The user then goes about their work within System B.

Step 3: When the user is finished with the task in System B and submits their work, System B passes a series of parameters and values back to System A via the post-back URI. System A performs some validation, writes the results into the database, then issues a command to System B to end the session (while I say session, this is not what you'd think of a true session as there's not state information) and System B closes the child window.

The majority of the time, this process works. Both vendors support this process. However, sometimes this process fails either in Step 1 or Step 3. The failure exhibits as either a hard error (as in Step 1) by System B as it doesn't receive the information it needs and expects in the query string, or an error by which System B sends its data back to System A (as in Step 3), but System A fails to retrieve the data. The latter error does not present to the user, nor does it generate any error log data. It simply doesn't exist. We only know about it after the fact when the user looks in System A for their work and there is nothing there.

And since it was already brought up, System A is performing a URL Encode/Decode on the query string data.

Since the error is intermittent, and I'm unable to replicate in my QA environment, I only have guesswork to go off of.

Comment: tl;dr. You could have just asked whether `?` may be substituted for `&` in a querystring. The answer is "no" (though it'll do _other_ things, not "break" per se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will not work right. What you need to do is to use the PHP UrlEncode function to encode all values when you form an URL. That will make PHP decode the original values properly.

```
http://www.php.net/urlencode
```

If you are going to put the URL in a HTML page, for instance on a  or  tags, you need to also use HtmlSpecialChars after URL encode.

```
http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars
```

Answer (score 3):

Did some quick tests in PHP because I was curious myself.  Here's a list of URLs and what shows up in $_GET from each one:

```
http://192.168.1.200/test.php?var1=test&var2=anotherTest
array(2) { ["var1"]=> string(4) "test" ["var2"]=> string(11) "anotherTest" }

http://192.168.1.200/test.php?var1=test?var2=anotherTest
array(1) { ["var1"]=> string(21) "test?var2=anotherTest" }

http://192.168.1.200/test.php?var1=test&?var2=anotherTest
array(2) { ["var1"]=> string(4) "test" ["?var2"]=> string(11) "anotherTest" }

http://192.168.1.200/test.php?var1=test?&var2=anotherTest
array(2) { ["var1"]=> string(5) "test?" ["var2"]=> string(11) "anotherTest" }

http://192.168.1.200/test.php??var1=test&var2=anotherTest
array(2) { ["?var1"]=> string(4) "test" ["var2"]=> string(11) "anotherTest" }
```

So basically, the second '?' is always treated as part of the data.  Could be jacking up variables names or causing other issues, dunno.

Comment: Also - first thing, I would sniff all network traffic to see exactly what is being passed back and forth.  You can probably get most of what you need from the Network tab in Firefox's Firebug.  To get a more detailed view and the ability to intercept HTTP requests in real time, run all internet traffic through a proxy like Burp Proxy (free).

Answer (score 1):

According to [section 3.4 of the URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) (#3986):

> The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?")
> character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character or by the
> end of the URI.
>
> query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
>
> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
> within the query component.  Beware that some older, erroneous
> implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as
> the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently because
> they fail to distinguish query data from path data when looking for
> hierarchical separators.  However, as query components are often used
> to carry identifying information in the form of "key=value" pairs and
> one frequently used value is a reference to another URI, it is
> sometimes better for usability to avoid percent- encoding those
> characters.

So, as I read that, a non-encoded `?` is allowed, but it may represent data, not necessarily a transition between data segments. In my limited experience, I've never seen this done in practice. I could imagine that some URL query parsing packages (especially home-brew ones) could miss this detail and potentially choke when they encounter a second `?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.php?parm1=val1&parm2=val2?parm3=val3&…
```

No, you shouldn't/can't do this, and it will result in unexpected consequences, which it sounds like you're starting to witness.  You will need to find a solution that doesn't create this scenario.  If you have an opportunity to create this url and process it's construction, you certainly can use & instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are problematic.

But since your system works sometimes maybe you can intercept those URLs within your webserver , for example Apache has mod_rewrite that allow you to redirect those URLs to another script, and then try create a clean_url script that will fix the URL then call( forward to ) your system B script with the fixed quotation mark replaced with the & character.

If you able todo make the first way you can also do it on reverse way.

Hope it solves your problem.